# Windesign : problem with relative identifier when generating logical model

Tags: database, uml, class-diagram

I'm at a loss. I don't know if anyone here uses windesign (I only found two questions here relative to the software when searching), but I encountered something that baffles me and I couldn't find any answer on the web as to why this might have happened. I figure it must be something about the parameters, but I couldn't find which one to alter.

So this is kind of a training / school project. We have this UML schema to complete, translate into a conceptual schema, add identifiers and then generate logical schema. This roughly looks like this :
[image: UML schema]

So as you can note, there are compositions here. In the conceptual schema, they are supposed to be translated as relative identifiers (the "R" between parenthesis).

[image: Conceptual schema]

As you can see, everything is normal until then. When converting to logical schema, the relative identifier is supposed to be translated as the identifiers of previous tables. For example, if you have rooms in a building, rooms can be identified as . This way of constructing the identifier can be found in planes and flights for example.

But here is the moment everything becomes complicated :

[image: logical schema]

As you can see, the relative identifier is translated with the names of the associations instead of the names of the other tables' identifiers.

If anyone has any idea as to why that might happen, I would be glad to hear about it.

I have tried changing parameters on generation of the logical schema, but it didn't do much (it did change things, but just not that). I also have tried googling a lot, with different terms, but was always falling back on the same pages (official windesign guides). Not many people seem to use it, and not many people ask question about it. So if anyone knows anything about this, you're welcome to answer as it bothers me a bit. That's not a big deal, but it's a bit annoying not being able to generate this correctly.

Thank you for reading, have a nice day.

Comment: Was curious since I had not heard of it. Seems it's a pure French product. I guess you are at a loss. Contact the company...

Comment: If you go in the generation options,  can you try, unchecking (empty box) the option "Utiliser le code relation dans le code des clés étrangères" ?  (maybe you have to do this already at the first stage for transforming UML to MLD, and not only when transforming MLD in MPD)

Comment: Dear rznrd,  could you please answer my question in the comment? It's difficult to advise, not knowing which generation configuration you did use.

Comment: @Christophe Don't worry. You know there are quite some posters which ask and (almost) never come back.

Comment: Hello @Christophe ! I'm here, and sorry about the delay. I did not have my work computer with me, so I couldn't test it and answer. Now I am here, and I must say I have tried it, and it didn't change anything... I have tested almost every configuration option of the generation and it's still the same. I guess it must be in more advanced options ? I don't know the software much, I don't know if there's more advanced options about that.